# Limiting Pan Gesture to a Set Frame

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have been searching on StackOverflow for a couple days and none of the answers out there work.

I have a UIImageView and I am trying to be able to move a label around inside of it. Right now I am able to move the label around, but it goes outside the bounds of the UIImageView.

Here is my code so far for the pan gesture:

```
var initialCenter = CGPoint()

    @objc func userDragged(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        guard let senderView = pan.view else { return }
        guard let parentView = senderView.superview else { return }

        let translation = pan.translation(in: imageHolder)

        if pan.state == .began {
            self.initialCenter = senderView.center
            print(self.initialCenter)
        }

        // update the position.
        if pan.state == .changed {

            let newCenter = CGPoint(x: initialCenter.x + translation.x, y: initialCenter.y + translation.y)
            senderView.center = newCenter

        } else if pan.state == .ended || pan.state == .cancelled {

            print("ended or cancelled")

            let finalCenter = CGPoint(x: senderView.center.x, y: senderView.center.y)
            senderView.center = finalCenter
        } else {
            senderView.center = initialCenter
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the label to the imageView here.

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // imageHolder is UIImageView.

    imageHolder.clipsToBounds = true
    imageHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    //the label is called labelView here

      imageHolder.addSubview(self.labelView)
      imageHolder.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     self.labelView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


}
```

[image]

Comment: Just tried this, unfortunately it doesn't even allow me to move the label. Once I add it back into a UIView it lets me move it, but outside the bounds of the image and the screen itself.

Comment: Is your label linking with labelView?

Comment: Is there any other inageview? Here the image holder is the only uiimageview

Comment: This is the hierarchy of the views: UIViewController -> UIView *imageHolder -> UIImageView *imageView -> UIView *contentHolder -> UILabel *label maybe this may help with visualization.

Comment: You are supposed  to make it simple and all UILabel and UIImageView should have isUserInteractionEnabled = true.

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way, I am able to move it around by enabling isUserInteractionEnabled, but it still goes out of the bounds of the image. I have it clipsToBounds set to true.

Comment: Is that same as shown in my image? You may clip all view between label and imagehold .

Comment: In my setting there are only two views. One is image holder and one is label. Hope you got it